# Hibernate Criteria - Exclude records with same id but different attribute values

Tags: hibernate, criteria

I'm trying to find records where status = "a" for a Person 
but exclude records where the same person has another record with a status="b"

SELECT * FROM Person WHERE  STATUS = 'a'
AND Person_id NOT IN (SELECT Person_id FROM Person WHERE STATUS = 'b' AND Person_id IS NOT NULL)

Appreciate the help

Comment: Could you give an idea of what your schema looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You can write subqueries using Criteria API via [DetachedCriteria](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core/reference/en/html/querycriteria.html#querycriteria-detachedqueries):

```
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(Person.class);
dc.setProjection(Property.forName("id")); // select person_id
dc.add(Property.forName("status").eq("b")); // where status = 'b'

Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Person.class);
c.add(Property.forName("id").notIn(dc)); // where id not in (above subquery)
c.add(Property.forName("status").eq("a")); // and status = 'a'
c.list(); // TODO: handle results
```